# При первой загрузке не отображается slick

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Есть [сайт](http://rb-clipmaking.ru/), на главной странице два slick слайдера, один из них отображается нормально, а второй - при первой загрузке пуст, со второй загрузки нормально. После очистки кэша, повторяется. Т.е. те кто заходят на сайт первый раз видят пустой слайдер.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Пробуй https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48254835/slick-slider-width-0-on-initial-page-load или $('.your_hidden_slider_class_or_id').slick("refresh");

Comment: Ни один вариант не сработал. Что то не так с параметром width, что обертка, что каждый слайд имеют width=0

Comment: Уже работает? открыл в разных браузерах вроде работает. Если нет попробуй убрать у этого блока в цсс flex.

Comment: А вы кэш почистите, баг проявляется только при первой загрузке

Comment: А если убрать display:flex то загружается нормально. Но вспоминаю, что я флекс использовал потому, что не мог вертикально отцентровать div{dispaly:block}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Убираешь dislpay:flex;
А для центрирования картинок попробуй:

```
.partners .slick-slide {
position:relative;
}
.partners .slick-slide img{
position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Вывод. Не следует менять стандартный display:block на другой

Answer (score 2):

Если у родителя (сам slick или html структура к которой подключен слайдер) вашего слайда (.slick-slide) изменен display (inline-block, flex и т.д), то причина скорее всего заключается в этом. Лично я решил это так - Убрал у родителя и самого слайда display: flex;, а выровнял все это дело с помощью float: left;

Вот структура, но она не полная:

```
<div class="about__photos photos">
    <div class="photos__items">
        <div class="photos__item">
            <div class="photos__photo-wrap photo-wrap">
                <img class="photo-wrap__photo ibg" src="img/About/01.jpg" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.slick {
    // Слайдер
    &-slider {
    }
    // Ограничивающая оболочка
    &-list {
    }
    // Лента слайдов
    &-track {
        // dislpay: flex; - именно в этом могла быть ошибка
    }
    // Слайд
    &-slide {
        float: left; // этим свойством я заменил flex, можно попробовать задать display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно выровнять flex, только картинки нужно взять в див. И тогда получится так

```
    .slick-track {
      display: flex;
     }

    <div class="slider">
       <ul class="slides1">
         <div><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" /></div>
         <div><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /></div>
         <div><img src="images3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
       </ul>
    </div>
```